# Google Spreadsheets create and upload to a user-chosen folder on google drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-picker, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to set up the following flow.

1. User clicks on a button.
2. Button Triggers Google Picker's 'Select Drive folder'
3. After folder is selected, folder ID is returned
4. `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create` method is triggered. A spreadsheet is created that is populated with certain user data.
5. Spreadsheet is sent to the selected user folder.

I've seen this implemented in Google Apps Script, so I know it's possible.

So far I've got:

```
    var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
        .setIncludeFolders(true)
        .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
        .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);


    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .addView(docsView)
        .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken)
        .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
        .setCallback(this._pickerCallback)
        .build();

    picker.setVisible(true);
```

Which allows the user to select a folder and returns the folder info/id.

Then I've got this method:

```
     gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({
        "properties": {
            "title": title,
        },
        "sheets": [
            sheet1,
            sheet2,
            sheet3,
        ]
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Which creates the Google Spreadsheet. Unfortunately it's automatically uploaded to drive.

How and where in this process, could I specify the folder for the spreadsheet to upload to?

Comment: Since the file is already in the drive root, try using the [Inserting a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) guide. You'll do this by passing the ID of the parent folder where you want to store the file.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna switch to google drive api and use **gapi.client.drive**

In this case your method should look something like this

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({

    'resource' : {
                   'name' : 'mySpreadSheet',
                   'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                   'parents': ['folderId']
                 }

}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```